# Toggle columns visible based on checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't understand why this is not doing anything...? Hopefully a simple solution for someone.

I have columns A:B hidden and a checkbox in D1 that when checked I would like to show/hide the columns. (this script was watered down from the second one below as I was trying to just test the basics).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != "D1") return;

  if (e.value == "TRUE") {
    ui.alert('Checkbox checked');
    //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().hideColumns(1, 3);
  }
  else if (e.value == "FALSE") {
    ui.alert('Checkbox unchecked');
    //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().showColumns(1, 3);
  }
}
```

I have also tried a different approach, this is ultimately an exact replica of my needs.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  //Ensure on sheet.
  if(activeSheet.getName() == 'Sheet3' && activeSheet.getRange(1,4).getValue() == "TRUE"){
        //ui.alert('Cell toggled on');
        activeSheet.showColumns(1,3);
  }else if (activeSheet.getName() == 'Sheet3' && activeSheet.getRange(1,4).getValue() == "FALSE"){
        //ui.alert('Cell toggled off');
        activeSheet.hideColumns(1,3);
  };
};
```

Link to test sheet if needed: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mMxyTpLk5ixldcbPwehMqFz7vfEnTy4fkgRgcdDH3WM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- If you actually use your showing script. `ui` is not defined.
- You can use the event object.
- In order to confirm the checkbox, you can also use `isChecked()`. When the method of `isChecked()` of Class Range is used, when the range is the checkbox, the boolean type (true or false) is returned. When the range is not a checkbox, `null` is returned. By this, it can be checked whether the cell is a checkbox.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet3" || range.rowStart != 1 || range.columnStart != 4) return;
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if (range.isChecked() === true) {
    ui.alert('Checkbox checked');
    sheet.hideColumns(1, 3);
  } else if (range.isChecked() === false) {
    ui.alert('Checkbox unchecked');
    sheet.showColumns(1, 3);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)

Comment: Do you know what I would change to allow for two editable sheets instead of one? If I add `if((sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet3" || sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet4") || range.rowStart != 1 || range.columnStart != 4) return;`  it breaks.

Comment: @Kevin P. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `Do you know what I would change to allow for two editable sheets instead of one?`, in this case, how about `if (!["Sheet3", "Sheet4"].includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.rowStart != 1 || range.columnStart != 4) return;`?

Comment: @Kevin P. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new issue was resolved.